# Populating turn feature class without having turn tables

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, feature-class, overlapping-features, turns

I would like to insert a turn feature class to my network.

I have created the tool but cannot populate it.

When I created it as a standalone shapefile arcgis tells me that it is not part of a network, whereas when i create it in a network dataset it tells me that the first node could not be snapped on the edge.

any ideas?

Comment: Have you "created the tool" or created a turns feature class?  If the latter, then what were the precise steps that you performed?

Comment: Sry 
I created the turns feature class using the geoproccesing tool. 
I then imported it into the dataset (containing the road network)
then i turned the dataset into a network dataset

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with this and any other requested clarifications.